# how to use electron cookies in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cookies, electron

I am working with electron and i want to use cookies conditionally. If it is a electron app then use Electron Cookies otherwise use angular cookies. I am facing problem in declaring the cookies in my angular app for electron.

As per the  [Electron's Cookie Document](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/cookies), we need to declare it using `require` but i want to use it in `.ts` file

So far, I've tried

`const { session } = require('electron');`

`declare function require(name:string);
const { session } = require('electron');`

`import * from 'electron';`

`import * as session from 'electron';`

All the approaches generates error while compiling or stop the script to execute at runtime.

Can anybody please help me and guide how can i use Electron-cookie in my porject.

Answer (score -1):

you need to webpreferences something like this

```
webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                webSecurity: true,
                allowEval: false,
                allowRunningInsecureContent: false,
                contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
                enableRemoteModule: true, // turn off remote
                preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
            },
```

nodeIntegration and enableRemoteModulke very important.
And in your preload.js create a window function

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'session',
    {
        set: (cookie) => {
          remote.session.defaultSession.cookies.set(cookie).then(() => {
            console.log('Cookie Saved')
          }, (error) => {
            console.error(error)
          })
        },
        // Returns Promise<Cookie[]>
        get: () => {
           return remote.session.defaultSession.cookies.get({}).then((cookies) => {
                console.log(cookies);
                return cookies
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
              })
        },
    }
  )
```

Finally in you angular2+ project execute the function like this

```
window['session'].get({}) || window['session'].set(cookie);
```

Comment: Ideally, this should use `ipcRenderer` to call the `session.defaultSession.cookies` APIs from the main process. `remote` was removed from Electron recently. This is also a bit misleading because `contextIsolation` is not turned off so `nodeIntegration: false` will have no effect (which is why you need to use `contextBridge`).